# How to add 'All' option for Angular Material paginator?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like an option to display all rows in the table. Angular Material only supports numbers for page size options. I need something like this:

```
[pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 'All']"
```

Comment: not possible as `pageSizeOptions` is a numeric array

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try this:

```
[dataSource] = "dataSource"
...
[pageSizeOptions] = "[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, dataSource.data.length]"
```

Comment: @Omar this my dataSource.data.length is 16 it shows after 10 but i want to show in last how it is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

please see the actual result 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpnbha-z4l4zf?file=app/table-pagination-example.ts

1) table-pagination-example.html

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="getPageSizeOptions()
```

2) table-pagination-example.ts

```
maxall : number=20;
ngOnInit() {
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
getPageSizeOptions(): number[] {
if (this.dataSource.paginator.length>this.maxall)
return [5, 10, 20,  this.dataSource.paginator.length];
else
return [5, 10, 20, this.maxall];
}
}
```

3)style.css

```
mat-option:last-child:before{
content: 'All';
float: left;
text-transform: none;
top: 4px;
position: relative;
}
mat-option:last-child .mat-option-text{
display: none;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: this will override any mat-option on the HTML how can it be done and just focus on the paginator options instead of every mat-options

Comment: If the goal of the `maxAll` parameter is to cap the maximum pagesize in case of a datasource with a lot of items then you might want to flip your `if` statement...

Comment: As wrabarias said, this replaces the style for all mat-options. Is there a way to specify only the mat-option within the mat-paginator?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this in your component html file under mat-paginator : 
"`[pageSizeOptions]="getPageSizeOptions()`"

And in your css file add following CSS, that will change the total length variable content with "All" Text :

```
mat-option:last-child:before{
    content: 'All';
    float: left;
    text-transform: none;
    top: 4px;
    position: relative;
}
mat-option:last-child .mat-option-text{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

And in your component .ts file:

```
getPageSizeOptions(): number[]{
    console.log(this.paginator.length);
    if(this.paginator.length>this.maxperpage)
    return [5, 10,50,this.maxperpage, this.dataSource.data.length];
    else
    return [5,10,50, this.maxperpage];
  }
```

Hopefully this will help!!!

Comment: Hello,

I tried your code. For a table with less than 20 data sets. For All 20 is still output, because maxall : number=20;

How can you always output the exact number of records and dependent on a fixed value assignment?

Answer (score 1):

The Angular Material Paginator does not directly support an "All" option for page size. From the information and discussions in this thread, I've found a workaround that **targets the Paginator specifically**, and doesn't interfere with other mat-option elements in the application. Here's a step-by-step guide:

**Step 1: Modify your TypeScript component**

Start by adding a variable named maxall in your TypeScript component. This will represent the maximum number of rows per page before adding the "All" option.

```
export class YourComponent {
  maxall: number = 20;
  // ...
}
```

Next, ensure you're setting the paginator for your data source in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.topPaginator;
  // ...
}
```

Then, create a method to dynamically generate the `pageSizeOptions`:

```
getPageSizeOptions(): number[] {
  if (this.dataSource.data.length <= this.maxall)
    return [5, 10, this.dataSource.data.length];
  else
    return [5, 10, 20, this.dataSource.data.length];
}
```

This method checks if the total number of rows is less than or equal to `maxall`. If it is, the "All" option is set to the total number of rows. Otherwise, it's set to 20.

**Step 2: Modify your HTML template**

In your Paginator component, use `getPageSizeOptions()` to dynamically set `pageSizeOptions`:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="getPageSizeOptions()" ... ></mat-paginator>
```

**Step 3: Apply CSS**

Lastly, apply CSS to visually replace the last option with "All". Note that you need to target the specific `mat-select-panel` of the paginator. This can be achieved by using its `aria-label` attribute.

```
.mat-select-panel[aria-label="Items per page:"] mat-option:last-child::before {
  content: 'All';
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.mat-select-panel[aria-label="Items per page:"] mat-option:last-child .mat-option-text {
  display: none;
}
```

With this workaround, the last option in the paginator's dropdown will display as "All", allowing users to select it to view all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpnbha-5ewyqw?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.html
(forked from rahul tailor's answer)

---

In case you have non optional pagination on the backend you want to send the page size to the API.

Therefore you have to know the parameter in advance.
In this case you can use the maximal Integer value (2'147'483'647) of Java (or any other limit that is suitable for your situation)

This workaround will only change the label, in the background your predefined maximal value will be used.

component.html

```
<mat-paginator (page)="paginatorHtmlElement.nativeElement.querySelector('div.mat- 
    select-value > span > span').innerHTML = paginator.pageSize == 2147483647? 'All': paginator.pageSize" 
    #paginator #paginatorElement
    [length]="dataSource.totalItemCount 
    [pageIndex]="0" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 2147483647]" 
    [pageSize]="10">
</mat-paginator>
```

component.ts

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator)
paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('paginatorElement', {read: ElementRef})
paginatorHtmlElement: ElementRef;
```

global stylesheet (styles.css)

```
mat-option[ng-reflect-value='2147483647'] > span {
   display: none;
}

mat-option[ng-reflect-value='2147483647']:last-child:after {
   content: 'Max' !important;
   visibility: visible !important;
   display: block !important;
   position: absolute !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
}`
```

Its still a workarround but it also allows you to use a large page size option like 10000 as the maximal size and display it in a more readable way.

If you use another value as your max page size just replace the value 2147483647 in my snippets.

Comment: Tried this implementation, but it won't work in prod environments by default as `ng-reflect-value` are for dev only

Answer (score 0):

The many of the answers above do not work with data called from a database due to loading time of the GET. And some have a bunch of unneeded code and CSS... What I did was as follows:

In your template for the paginator:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="!pageLoading ? getPageSizes() : [5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
```

And then in the .ts file:

```
getPageSizes(): number[] {
    if (this.dataSource.data.length > 20) {
      return [5, 10, 20, this.dataSource.data.length];
    }
    else {
     return [5, 10, 20];
    }
  }
```

And lastly the .css file:

```
::ng-deep mat-option:last-child:before{
  content: 'All';
}
::ng-deep mat-option:last-child .mat-option-text{
  display: none;
}
```

I noticed sometimes the styling I put on the mat-(whatevers) classes sometimes would not work. ::ng-deep fixes that and makes sure that your styling will effect it.

The lambda expression checks to see if your page is loading the data, if it is then there are some "default" choices. If not, and thus if the dataSource is populated, it will call the function and display the default choices + the "All" choice.
**pageLoading** is just a boolean that I set initially to TRUE and then inside the subscribe of the call to my service to GET the data *at the very end, but still inside the subscribe function*, I set **pageLoading** to FALSE. The answers above will not work with database data because of the loading time to GET it and thus the dataSource length being null. So unless your data is hard coded... the answers above probably won't work (nicely).

Answer (score 0):

```
[pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100, this.paginator.length]"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So, when you're dealing with multiple paginators, like around 2 or 3 of them, you can actually smoothly add an option for 'All' right into the choices for pagination. The cool thing is, doing this doesn't mess with the mat-option elements at all.

On the other hand,If you employ the ng-reflect approach, it might encounter issues when transitioning to a production environment due to changes in Angular's internal workings.I've got a simple, straightforward solution that I've personally tried and tested that is effective in my case:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8150#issuecomment-1671072641